SuiteCommerce Advanced - We have Netsuite 2024.1, can i install 2 different bundles of SCA
We have Netsuite 2024.1 and SuiteCommerce Vinson (bundle 134179), we are wanting to install the bundle for SuiteCommerce Advanced 2023.1 (bundle 468610), will that install make any changes to Vinson and stop it from working?
I have been trying to develop on Vinson but I am not able to deploy as the latest source for Vinson points to API 2015_1 and when you try to deploy that on 2024.1 it does not allow that old API.
So I am looking to deploy an additional SCA version 2023.1 and build the site on that. But I am worried that if I install the latest bundle it will stop the current Vinson version from working.

SuiteCommerce Advanced will likely create a separate folder and a separate SSP for the newly installed version. You also select which version the domain uses, or in Vinson’s case, it could be defined in the Website setup record. You shouldn’t have an issue installing the new version since they are different bundles. Either way just be sure everything is ok, I would first try doing it in Sandbox (if you have access to one), or would raise a Netsuite support ticket to have them confirm this is possible without disrupting the existing website.
